How many folders will be created based on hierarchy?
I have following FolderPath data in a column in a table. I want to find total number of distinct folders that will be created from these path grouped across WorkspaceID. What should a query to get this total folder count that needs to be created. For below example total of 10 folder will be created based on folder hierarchy. 1st row, 3 folders. 2nd row, 1 folder, as "a" parent is already created as part of row1. 3rd row, 1 folder, as "a" parent is already created as part of row1. For row 4, one folder will be create as folder a and b are already created as part of row1. For row 5, 2 folders will be create as top folder a already created as part of row1. 1 folder will be created for each row 6 and 7.



WorkspaceID
FolderPath




1
a\b\c


1
a\d


1
a\e


1
a\b\a


1
a\a\a


1
b


1
c



Am expecting a SQL Server query

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

What version is sql-server ?

You can use recursive CTE perhaps:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  WorkspaceID, FolderPath, FolderPath AS part, 1 AS level
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (1, N'a\b\c')
        ,   (1, N'a\d')
        ,   (1, N'a\e')
        ,   (1, N'a\b\a')
        ,   (1, N'a\a\a')
        ,   (1, N'b')
        ,   (1, N'c')
    ) t (WorkspaceID,FolderPath)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  WorkspaceID, FolderPath, LEFT(part, len(part) - charindex('\', REVERSE(part))), level + 1
    FROM    cte c
    WHERE   charindex('\', REVERSE(part)) > 0
)
SELECT  count(DISTINCT part),WorkspaceID
FROM    cte
group by WorkspaceID

It strips away the path one by one and then calculate the distinct parts.
